# How do you add a confirmation before an action in Pinia?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

Basically the title: I need to ask user a confirmation before a certain action is called and be able to break its execution.

The way I did it now is like this:

```
// in my main App.vue
store.$onAction(({name, store, args}) => {
    if (name === 'setCurrentItem') {
        if (!confirm(t('confirm.quit_editing')) {
            throw new Error('User aborted');
        }
    }
});
```

But it feels hacky, as throwing an error there doesn't actually make sense (I see it as another execution path).

There are some reasons that I don't want to put this into the store action method:

- the confirm is an UI action which doesn't belong into the store
- I also use i18n which doesn't play nice outside of a component

I cannot place this into a component either, as this is called from several components.

The way I'm seeing this happen is via aplugin, as the Pinia docs states that a plugin can

> Intercept actions and its results

But unfortunately I'm not finding any example of doing this on the docs or anywhere else.

Comment: confirm() is a hack itself because it blocks the execution. onAction can be used with promises so you're not limited to it, but afaik you won't be able to prevent an action, you likely don't do that currently, you can debug if an action is being triggered. The use of throw is justified here because you need to handle the abort somehow where the action is consumed and this can be achieved with errors

Comment: In this case it's not obvious that there's a need for onAction at all. Since you target specific actions, you can handle confirmation directly there with some reusable code, possibly an action from another store that handles dialogs

Comment: @EstusFlask that's the only way i could think at _that_ moment. I posted an aswer on how I eventually did it without `throw`ing anything in the process :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long story short I've done it by creating a few utility functions that will wrap the pinia store actions.

```
const setCurrentItemWithConfirm = (status) => {
    if (!confirm(t('alerts.confirm_dirty_collection'))) { return; }

    return store.setCurrentItem(status);
}
```

I've followed the guides to move Pinia & i18n outside components and things looks good:

- https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html
- https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/general.html#global

So... yay?